# when Relative path of input file Included in script Error reported -VBA

Tags: vba

I have this macro which is taking input excel, and generating excel report and copying it. Below code works fine when i am running manually from excel with msg dialog box, however when i tried to pass relative path of input file, i am getting  "Runtime Error 9"-Subscript out of range.  While debugger points to Each sh as error context.

How do I fix this?

```
 Sub buildSCTR()
    '
    ' Merge CSV and built pivot for SCTR
    ' Ver 0.1
    ' 5-July-2017    P. Coffey
    '

Const FILELIMIT = 0 'used to hardcode number of files will work with.  better ways exist but this will do for now

Dim firstFilename As String
Dim secondFilename As String
Dim outputFilename As String
Dim element As Variant
Dim dirLocation As String
Dim macroWb As Object
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim samName As String
Dim RootFolder As String

'code allows for multiple import, but using it for one one import here
Dim filenameArr(0 To FILELIMIT) As Variant 'so can push cells into it later
Dim inputSelected As Variant 'has to variant to iterate over via for each even though its a string

Set macroWb = ThisWorkbook

RootFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path

'get new csv to load
    'Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
     ' With fd
      '  .AllowMultiSelect = True
       ' .Title = "Pick SC file to load"
        '.Filters.Clear
        '.Filters.Add "csv", "*.csv*"

        'If .Show = True Then

         '   i = 0
          '  For Each inputSelected In .SelectedItems
           '     filenameArr(i) = Dir(inputSelected)     'kludgy....
            '    dirLocation = Split(inputSelected, filenameArr(i))(0)
             '   i = i + 1
            'Next inputSelected

       ' Else
        '  MsgBox ("Nothing selected")
         ' Exit Sub
       ' End If
      'End With

    Application.StatusBar = "Starting to update"

    element = RootFolder + "/Output/_SCT_Details_With_Comments.csv"


   ' For Each element In filenameArr()
        If Not IsEmpty(element) Then    'as hardcoded length of array have to do this
            Workbooks.Open (element)
            Call CopyWorkbook(CStr(element), macroWb.Name)
            'close csv as done with it
           Workbooks(element).Close SaveChanges:=False
       End If
    'Next element

'convert to table
    samName = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
    ActiveSheet.Name = samName & "_SCT_Data"

    'assumes col A is contiguous
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A1:$U" & lastrow), , xlYes).Name = "SCT"

'build pivot
    Dim objWs As Worksheet
    Dim objPT As PivotTable
    Dim objPC As PivotCache

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Summary"
    Set objWs = ActiveSheet

    Set objPC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "SCT")
    Set objPT = objPC.CreatePivotTable(objWs.Range("A3"), TableName:="SCTR")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SCTR").PivotFields("Target_SC")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SCTR").PivotFields("Action")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SCTR").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "SCTR").PivotFields("PNI_SC"), "Count of PNI_SC", xlCount

'have to do it in this order else vba was removing pni_sc from row field...who knows why
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SCTR").PivotFields("PNI_SC")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

'--update sheet with last sync info
    macroWb.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value = samName
    macroWb.Sheets("Summary").Range("A3").NumberFormat = "h:mm dd/mm"


'save as new file
    Dim timestamp As String
    timestamp = Format(Now(), "mmddhh")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        dirLocation & samName & "_SCTR_" & timestamp & ".xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

'exit msg
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Completed - saved file as " & dirLocation & samName & "_SCTR_" & timestamp & ".xlsm")


End Sub

Sub CopyWorkbook(source As String, target As String)


'copy all sheets from one workbook to another

Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

   Set wb = Workbooks(target)
   For Each sh In Workbooks(source).Worksheets
      sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
   Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: workbooks " source" and "target"  must be opened before you can copy the sheets.

Comment: Thanks for reply , can you please suggest script or modify my code to open source and target before kicking of copy.

Comment: @ sam, after have read your code more in detail, it looks like both workbooks are open.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is due to the fact that the source contains the fullname of the workbook (path included) and Excel expects only the shortname of the workbook (without the path)

so adapt the call instruction like this

```
Call CopyWorkbook(ActiveWorkbook.Name, macroWb.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for quick resolution .i am able to run and generate outptut as expected

Comment: Could you validate the answer if this is an answer to your question ? thanks

Comment: Yes, suggested changes made each sh run sucessful ,which eventually generated output excel .